# AngularJs Dependencies

Tags: html, angularjs

This code doesn't work when I pass `ngRoute` as a dependency. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
    <link href="vendor/angular/angular-material.min.cs" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular-animate.min.js'></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src='vendor/angular/angular-material.min.js'></script>



</head>
<body>
    <h3>HELLO!!! {{2+2}}</h3>

    <data-ng-view></data-ng-view>


 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error is showing up in the console?

Comment: Also check network tab for errors

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/modulerr?....
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:43
    at r (angular.min.js:8)
    at g (angular.min.js:42)
    at fb (angular.min.js:46)
    at c (angular.min.js:22)
    at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
    at Ae (angular.min.js:21)
    at angular.min.js:348
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)